# Edit read-only file in java

Tags: java, linux, text-files, readonly

I have a protect, read-only, text file on my Linux operating system that I have to make edits to. Of course I can goto the terminal and type:

```
sudo gedit /etc/ppp/options
```

I would then have to type my sudo password. My question is how do I give my java program "sudo" privileges to be able to write to this file and save those edits? I figured once I have given the program these privileges I could then use a BufferedWriter or PrintWriter to make edits.

To clarify, my program prompts the user for their administrative (sudo) password. How could I use this to grant access to this file for writing purposes?

Comment: How are your currently running your program?

Comment: @Malt What do you mean by this? I am unsure of how knowing that is useful to my question.

Comment: @DanielH maybe he can help you if he knows whether you are running the program through an ide or console

Comment: @CyanogenCX Alright, my apologizes.

Comment: @Malt I have a GUI (swing) that allows a user choose from a list of IP Addresses (they are used for connection purposes later on). When the user chooses one I need to edit the text file I mentioned above by placing this address into it. I figured I would use a BufferedWriter or a PrintWriter to make changes accordingly after the program has been given "sudo" access.

Comment: @DanielH It's all good, however I have no idea of how to answer your question.

Comment: @CyanogenCX no worries, maybe someone else will be able too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how do I give my java program "sudo" privileges to be able to write to this file and save those edits.

I think that the simple answer is that you can't.

Sudo works by checking a file to see if the user allowed to run a command, and optionally confirming his / her identity by asking for his / her password.  If both of these check out, then the `sudo` command executes the requested command as a different user; typically `root`.

However, in order to do this, the "sudo" program itself is implemented as a "setuid" program; i.e. a program that *itself* that runs with elevated privileges.  Without this, it cannot run the requested program "as root", and it can't even read the "/etc/sudoers" file.

So can we emulate "sudo" in Java?

Basically, no.  To do this, you would need to make the `java` command a "setuid" program.  But the `java` command can execute ANY java program written by anyone.  So a "setuid" `java` would allow anyone to run any java program with administrator privileges.  That would be **insanely** insecure.

---

So what are the alternatives?

1. You could use `ProcessBuilder` to "exec" the `sudo` command as an external command.  However, passing a password to `sudo` via its command line is not possible.  So you would need to either:

   - configure the `sudoers` file to allow the (specific) command to be executed without a password (potentially dangerous), or
   - figure out a way to use the `--askPass` hook to request the user's password securely from Java, or
   - use the `--stdin` option to read the user's password from standard input instead of the user's terminal.
2. Write a custom "setuid" (or "setgid") wrapper to execute the admin command.  Note: "setuid" shell scripts are fundamentally insecure.  A C / C++ wrapper is potentially the safest approach ... but you need to be sure that the wrapper can't be tricked into doing something dangerous / nasty by supplying clever arguments or environment variables.
3. Don't do it in Java.  Get the user to run the privileged command from the command line; e.g. using `sudo`.  You could potentially make it easier for the user by providing a script (shell, perl, whatever) to handle anything complicated, do sanity checking, etcetera.

My recommendation is approach #3 (in general).  It is the most secure and transparent approach.  (As an administrator / power-user, I would be *very uncomfortable* with some complicated / opaque Java application asking for my password to run `sudo` commands on my system.)

### WARNING

Doing this kind of thing safely and securely requires a good understanding of how UNIx / Linux security works.  There are numerous mistakes you could make (too many to list) that could compromise security, and allow users to run arbitrary programs as root, or other dangerous / destructive things.  Be careful, and get an real UNIX / Linux expert to review your implemented mechanism.

Comment: Hey thank you for your reply. I wanted to highlight two things. Firstly it is possible to pass the password from what I have read. Here is an article showing the use of sudo commands: http://alvinalexander.com/java/java-exec-processbuilder-process-1

Secondly, I dont allow the user to input any type of commands. They would be all preprogrammed in so there should be no worries. I have an array of options (JButtons) that the user can do and they can only do that. There would be no wiggle room for the user on this.

Comment: @DanielH - yea ... but can the user trust >>you<<??

Comment: You raise a very valid question. I am making this program for myself and for a community I am beginning to get involved with. The method they use is awful as it requires four terminals and it is just all around messy. I am not trying to be malicious at all, I am just trying to help. But I do see your point. I will do some thinking to figure out the right and best approach. Thank you.

Comment: @DanielH - it is not just maliciousness.  An honest mistake in a command run using `sudo` could be just as destructive.  People should have the ability to preview what is going to be executed ... just in case.

Comment: Okay I think that is fair. I will work on giving a preview before execution.